# Maximum number of breakdowns for an $8$ digit number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Breakdown an $8$ digit number into successive digits such that each number is a prime and with increasing values to the right. For example, with $23353593$ we have:

- $2-3-3-5-3593$
- $2-3-3-53-593$
- $2-3-3-53593$
- $2-3-353-593$
- $23-353-593$
- $233-53593$

We can see that the number $23353593$ has exactly $6$ breakdowns. My question is, what is the maximum number of breakdowns for an $8$ digit number, and what that $8$ digit number is?

Comment: Simply write a program to check it out if it is of great importance to you.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, thanks, but I'm not a computer programmer at all

Comment: But I don't expect a solution different from brute force. I don't think that mathematical theory will help here a lot. Your definition of a breakdown is so random and also based on the representation of the number and not on the number itself that I don't expect a nice theory behind it.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, I conjecture that the maximum would not exceed 18

Comment: I am quite sure that the first 4 digits of that number must be 2337

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $12$, which is given by the number $23374159$ :

- $2-3-3-7-41-59$
- $2-3-37-41-59$
- $2-3-3-7-4159$
- $23-37-41-59$
- $2-3-37-4159$
- $2-3-3-74159$
- $23-37-4159$
- $2-337-4159$
- $2-3-374159$
- $233-74159$
- $23-374159$
- $2-3374159$

  $23374159$ is the smallest 8 digit number with exactly $12$ "breakdowns", I don't know whether there exists another $8$ digit number with exactly $12$ breakdowns.

Answer (score 1):

If that $8$ digit number is a prime itself and also counted as a breakdown, then the smallest $8$ digit numbers with exactly $12$ breakdowns are $23373613$, $23374159$, and $23379397$ :

- $2-3-3-7-3613$
- $2-3-3-73-613$
- $2-3-3-73613$
- $2-3-37-3613$
- $2-3-373-613$
- $2-3-373613$
- $2-337-3613$
- $23-37-3613$
- $23-373-613$
- $23-373613$
- $233-73613$
- $23373613$